# Any way to (easily) determine the minimum width required to format a Framesetter?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-text

If I have a framesetter that I've initialised with a string like so

```
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);
```

I'd like to find the minimum width to display the largest string in the frame. Is there an easy way to do this? I can do it by iterating over the lines and runs and calculating it from there, but it seems like something that would have a method since it would calculate this internally.

I tried

```
CGSize sz = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0,0), NULL, CGSizeMake(1, CGFLOAT_MAX), NULL);
```

but it just returns a constant size which seems to be the width of a single glyph.

tia

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for widths, you should pass CGFLOAT_MAX for the width in your CGSizeMake to indicate that width is unconstrained.

Generally speaking, to find a height for a given width, pass CGSizeMake(myWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX), and to find a width for a single line of text, pass CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX).

Comment: Thanks for that - what I'm after is a way to find out the widths of words e.g. in 'This is a test' I want the width of the word 'test'. I can do it by pulling apart the strings and parsing myself. I thought there might be a way to do it in core-text, since the franesetter has to do this internally, but there seems no way of getting at this information.

Comment: If you break out your frame into lines, and your lines in turn into runs, you should find API there that'll allow you to get positions of individual characters as well as a tight bounding box for ranges of characters.